# What fence device setup would prevent a mutual-STONITH in a two-node RHEL cluster?

Tags: cluster, rhcs, fencing

I've got a Red Hat cluster (corosync+rgmanager) software on RHEL 6.6 on physical Dell servers with iDRAC.

This cluster is for stateless application (stunnel, a TLS gateway), so it doesn't need and doesn't have any shared disk. I prefer to keep this cluster as simple as possible, so I rather not add any iSCSI quorum disk (as of now, no qdisk at all).

My cluster.conf contains:

```
    <cman expected_votes="1" two_node="1"/>
```

In case my "heartbeat" link totally fails, my tests strongly suggest that this happens:

> If both nodes in a two-node cluster lose contact with each other,
>   don't they try to fence each other?
>
> They do. When each node recognizes that the other has stopped
>   responding, it will try to fence the other. It can be like a gunfight
>   at the O.K. Coral, and the node that's quickest on the draw (first to
>   fence the other) wins. Unfortunately, both nodes can end up going down
>   simultaneously, losing the whole cluster.  (quote from
>   https://fedorahosted.org/cluster/wiki/FAQ/CMAN)

Can any fencing device assure that such gunfight would only power down a single node? Surely iDRAC or vmWare agents cannot prevent this.

I'm thinking of some IPMI-enabled PDU that only acts sequentially, like this: if there is a request to power down a port, this request waits for all the ongoing power-down requests from others.

I cannot verify this in PDU documentation, but maybe someone have tried it at can recommend something that practically works that way.